# C implementation difference between map and unorderd_map

Tags: c++, c, dictionary, unordered-map

I'm rewriting a little C++ program to plain C, it's pretty trivial program which counts occurence of words in input using `map`. I'm using hashtable (structure containing size and array of pointers to linked node lists) of static size. I'm having trouble with rewriting following part to C

```
#if 1       // switch between 1 and 0
# include <tr1/unordered_map>
  typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string,int>  map_t;
#else
# include <map>
  typedef std::map<std::string,int>  map_t;
#endif
```

I have primarily implemented the unordered version using the hash function, I used it this way

```
#if 1    // switch between 1 and 0
    int hash_function(const char *key, int size);
#else
    #define hash_function(key, size) .......
#endif
```

but now I have no idea how should the macro look like since I want the table to be ordered and I have static size of the table. Because I have no experience with maps I don't know if there is any conventional way of implementing this.

I got an idea of using the table as 2 dimensional array, as simple matrix, and filling it column by column from top to bottom.

So again, is there any better, conventional way, of doing this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your flaw is overthinking the problem. Maps and unordered_maps solve completely different problem sets, and you're trying to make an unordered map solve a (ordered) map problem?

Comment: std::map are typically implemented using balanced binary trees (e.g. red-black tree), which is totally different from a hash table, and of course does not use a hash function.

Comment: If you want the table ordered, you cannot use an unordered_map

Comment: I forgot the "homework" tag, it's school assignment so I HAVE to do this this way... of course I cant use unordered_map, that is what's the switch between 0 and 1 in that if for

Comment: most likely, you just need to re-read the requirements. You've misunderstood the assignment, and are trying to do something completely nonsensical (and impossible)

Comment: There are no more informations regarding this part of code, I just have to rewrite it, + write some auxiliary functions. And I surely can't just ignore part of code

Comment: If that is really your assignment, than that piece of code should still probably use `typedef`s to pick alternate implementations of a map (except this time the LHS of the `typedef` should be one of your implementations).

Answer (score 1):

A pretty typical implementation of an ordered hashmap is just a regular hashmap with an additional linked list that goes through all the elements in order. The trick is to maintain this linked list correctly with every insertion and removal. The hash function doesn't (need to) change b/w and ordered and an unordered hashmap.

The main problem with your 2d array idea is that it consumes `n*sizeOfHashTable` space, most of which is wasted.

If you are implementing a sorted map, you usually take any ordered data structure like binary search tree and just let the keys (which are what you sort on) also have values associated with them. Then you don't use a hash function at all.

Comment: since it's an school assignment, I can't add any structures/lists, so I guess I'll have to settle with wasted space... thanks for your answer